# If f'>0 and f''<0, where is f(a)<a or f(a)>a?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Say that $f(x)$ is a function such that $f(x) \geq 0$ and the domain is $x \geq 0$. Moreover, $f'>0$ and $f''\leq 0$. Can we prove for which $a$ is $f(a) < a$ or $f(a)>a$?.

Comment: Can you precise  whether $f''<0$ or $f''\le 0$.

Answer (score 3):

We can find examples with strict inequalities for the $3$ cases:

- $f(a)>a$ (except in $0$) for $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x}$
- $f(a)<a$ (except in $0$) for $f(x)=\ln(x+1)$
- crossing in some $a\neq 0$ ($a=1$ here) for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$

Therefore the conditions stated are not sufficient to decide for a general behaviour.

Comment: Excellent! What other conditions would make possible to have f(a)>=a?

Comment: $f'\ge 1$ would work by integration, but it feels cheating. Though ultimately you need $f$ to have asymptotic behaviour greater than $x$, so this condition is more or less required at infinity.

Comment: What do you mean by "have asymptotic behaviour greater than x"? Could make an example? Is that a sufficient condition for f(a)>=a for any a?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $f(x)=x$, then:
$f(x)=x\geq0\\
f'(x)=1\geq0\\
f''(x)=0\leq0$ 
It satisfying all the conditions, yet, $f(a)$ not greater, or lesser than $a.\square$